# quotes in sql query

Tags: mysql

how can you add quotes in a sql query if the field names includes "-" or other charactors or if the field has a reserved name like "type" or others

```
SELECT `enclosure.id`, `enclosure.time`, `enclosure.note` 
FROM tbl.enclosure LEFT JOIN tbl.book ON book.enc_id=enclosure.id 
WHERE `book.book_id`='277' ORDER BY enclosure.time DESC, enc_id_ DESC
```

error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'enclosure.id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Have you already tried the backslash, `\\`?

Comment: Don't understand your question...what goes wrong, what do you want?

Comment: Well, you've done a nice job using the backticks (`), that should work. What's the problem?

Comment: What's the point of using backticks?

Comment: Try 'enclosure'.'id' (where ' = `). If that doesn't work either, the column id doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you correct, but I think you should replace

```
`book.bookid`
```

with

```
`book`.`bookid`
```

.

Answer (score 0):

you have something wrong in query..it must be like below ( you did not set alias for table )

```
SELECT `enclosure`.id`, `enclosure`.time`, `enclosure`.note` 
FROM tbl_enclosure  enclosure 
LEFT JOIN tbl_book book ON `book`.`enc_id`=`enclosure`.`id` 
WHERE `book`.book_id`='277' 
ORDER BY `enclosure`.`time` DESC, `enclosure`.`enc_id` DESC
```

Comment: i have set alias for `enclosure` for  `tbl_enclosure` and `book` for `tbl_book`